# Assign php true or false value to JS var

Tags: javascript, php

even after researching I am at a loss as to why the var is "undefined" and therefor not correctly evaluated as boolean.

I have even tired evaluating it as a string -- tcr_user=='true' with no success.

Everything else works fine except the true/false evaluation. Can anyone explain why?

```
$('.edit_product_link').addEvent('click',function(e) {
    if(!validateUser(this.id)) {
        if(e) e.stop();
        alert('<?php echo $objLanguage->GetText('__confirm_deny_edit__')  . '\n' .  $objLanguage->GetText('__confirm_deny_contact_admin__'); ?>');  
    };
});

function validateUser(lister_id) {
    var user_id =  <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['user_id']); ?>;
    var company_admin_id = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['company_admin_id']); ?>;
    var tcr_user = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['superadmin'])) { echo json_encode($_SESSION['superadmin']);}; ?>;

    console.log(tcr_user.type );   // undefined 

    if(user_id == lister_id || user_id == company_admin_id || tcr_user) {
        return true;        
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is showing by echo json_encode($_SESSION['superadmin']) ?

Comment: You have the possibility of having a line that syas `var tcr_user = ;`.  If you're going to have that `if` statement, wrap it around that `var` as well.

Comment: Thank you Pravat - both json_encode & JSON.parse() returned Boolean true (or false). Brad is absolutely correct- in exhausted brevity I omitted  the fail to false. Thank you both for your experience & time reviewing. ".typeof" still returns "undefined" - a mystery to me, even tried explicitly declaring it. Fortunately, with you not detecting any errors, it told me to look elsewhere - a poorly written (and ineffective) security feature (with no console error) was illuminated. Tired eyes miss details...  Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Brad said, you should assign value to the variable tcr_user in any case:

```
function validateUser(lister_id) {
    var user_id =  <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['user_id']); ?>;
    var company_admin_id = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['company_admin_id']); ?>;
    var tcr_user = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['superadmin'])) { echo json_encode($_SESSION['superadmin']);} else echo false; ?>;

    console.log(typeof tcr_user );   // use typeof to detect the type of variable

    if(user_id == lister_id || user_id == company_admin_id || tcr_user) {
        return true;        
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript var don't have type property.

If you do someVar.type with *undefined* someVar. It will get error:

```
var i = undefined;
i.type // TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

If you do someVar.type with *defined* someVar. It will get undefined:

```
var i = true;
i.type // undefined
```

And you need to parse json in javascript, or php just echo the json string.

```
var javascriptData = JSON.parse(<?php echo $phpData; ?>);
```

Comment: Properties are not a feature of the var construct, which simply binds (or rebinds) a name to a value. if we execute : `Object.prototype.type = function() { return typeof this; };` all objects will have a type property.

Comment: @AluanHaddad That would define a method, not a normal property, you would have to invoke it with `.type()`. You could make it a normal property using defineProperty: `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'type', {get: function() { return typeof this; }});`. However, this implementation of `.type` is not always accurate: `[].type // returns "object"`.

Comment: @UselessCode You are correct, I did not implement a property, rather a method. I should have  However, that `typeof array` in JavaScript  returns `"object"` is baked into the language's type system. For that matter, `typeof null` also returns `"object"`...